# How to define a type that is subject to several implicit conversions?

Tags: scala, slick

I'm working with slick 3.0. I'm just trying to centralise some database setup code into a trait.

The following is what I have:

```
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

object EventFixtures {

  val table = TableQuery[EventsTable]
  val data = Seq(...)

  def insertFixtures(db: Database): Int = {

    Await.result(db.run(table.schema.create), Duration.Inf)  
    Await.result(db.run(table ++= data), Duration.Inf).get
  }
}
```

I've lifted and shifted this to a trait:

```
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration


trait FixtureHelper {

  val data: Seq
  val table: ???

  def insertFixtures(db: Database) = {

    Await.result(db.run(table.schema.create), Duration.Inf)
    Await.result(db.run(table ++= data), Duration.Inf).get
  }
}
```

and I want to use it like:

```
object EventFixtures extends FixtureHelper {
  val data = Seq(...)
  val table = TableQuery[EventsTable]
}

// in test code:
EventFixtures.insertFixtures()
```

The problem is the type of `table`.

1. `table` has type: `slick.lifted.TableQuery[_ <: AbstractTable]`, and the line `++=` is only found if I use this type, but the implicit conversion of the seq doesn't happen anyway.
2. `table.schema` has type: `slick.profile.RelationalProfile#TableQueryExtensionMethods`, and this property isn't found if I declare `table` as in point 1.
3. `table.schema.create` has type: `slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$SchemaActionExtensionMethodsImpl`, and this property isn't found if I declare `table` as in point 2.

In the original code, where table is instantiated as a `TableQuery`, slick uses some implicit conversions to add the other properties. It also must be converting the `data` seq to an Iterable of `E#TableElementType`.

So how can I generically type `table` so that this trait will compile and all of these implicitly added members can be found?

I thought this would be simple, but it seems that unless I instantiate `TableQuery` with a concrete class, the whole thing falls apart. In fact, in my different fixture files, I do instantiate TableQuery with a concrete table, so all I need is to make the compiler know what properties and methods are available for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the tableTag and use it for creating a TableQuery , if your table class looks is defined as :

```
case class Events(....)

class EventsTable(tag: Tag)
  extends Table[Sample](tag, "sample_table") {
    .....
}
```

This is how you can implement :

```
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._
import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple.Tag
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

trait FixtureHelper {

  val data: Seq

  def insertFixtures[T,A <: Table[T]](tag : Tag => A ,db: Database) = {
  val table : TableQuery[A] = TableQuery(tag) // create the tableQuery from the tag
    Await.result(db.run(table.schema.create), Duration.Inf)
    Await.result(db.run(table ++= data.toIterable), Duration.Inf).get // ++= accepts only Iterable[] values
  }
}
```

and you can use it like

```
object EventFixtures extends FixtureHelper {
  val data = Seq(...)
}

// in test code:
val tag= new EventsTable(_)
EventFixtures.insertFixtures[Events,EventsTable](tag)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how did you know that? I mean, how can you tell, from looking at all of the implicit conversions that are going on what sort of types you need to use?

Comment: I am sorry , I din't get you. What about the code snippet , did it work ?

Comment: I haven't had chance to try it. But I want to know how you knew to do what you did. The type is implicitly converted, so how did you know which type to use?

Comment: A tableQuery for any table(in your code EventsTable) class is generally generated as : 
`val table : TableQuery[EventsTable] = TableQuery(new EventsTable(_))`

Comment: A **tableQuery** for any table class(in your code EventsTable) , is usually generated by the statement: 
`val table : TableQuery[EventsTable] = TableQuery(new EventsTable(_))`.. the **tag** i pass to the generic trait is `new Events(_)` and this tag as you can see is specific to each table , hence `TableQuey(tag)` statement in the trait generates specific tablequery for each table . Hope I answered your  point.